# Expectation of squared dot product of a constant vector and a random vector

Tags: probability

I've derived the following and I would like some feedback.

Given a random vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ where each element is drawn i.i.d from some unknown distribution that has bounded expectation and a constant vector $w \in \mathbb{R}^d$, I need to find $\mathbb{E}[(w \cdot x)^2]$.
Since $w \cdot x$ is a scalar, $(w \cdot x) = (w \cdot x)^T =  x^T \cdot w^T$

So,
$(w \cdot x)^2 = (w\cdot x) \cdot (w \cdot x) =(x^T \cdot w^T) \cdot (w\cdot x)$
Rearranging, $(x^T \cdot w^T) \cdot (w\cdot x) = x^T \cdot w^T \cdot w \cdot x = x^T \cdot ||w||_2^2 \cdot x$.
$\|w\|_2^2$ is a scalar, so $x^T \cdot \|w\|_2^2 \cdot x = \|w\|_2^2\cdot x^T \cdot x = \|w\|_2^2 \cdot \|x\|_2^2$.

Plugging back into expectation,
$\mathbb{E}[(w \cdot x)^2] = \mathbb{E}[\|w\|_2^2 \cdot \|x\|_2^2]$ = $\|w\|_2^2 \cdot \mathbb{E}[\|x\|_2^2]$

So, no matter how the elements of x are distributed, provided the expectation is bounded, the expectation of the square of a dot product is just the expectation of the squared norm of the random vector times the squared norm of the constant vector.

Is this correct, or did I miss something?

Thank you.

Comment: What does "random vector" exactly mean? A vector with all components except one exactly equal to the corresponding components of $w$ and the one other other component being $0$ or $1$ depending on a random choice is a random vector. Another one is a vector where each component is a evenly distributed random value between $-1$ and $1$. A third random vector is a vector with a fixed length pointing to a random direction. Another random vector is parallel zo $w$ but with a random length. There are so many ways of defining what a random vector is.

Comment: Use `\|` instead of `||` to get proper norm bars.

Comment: @joriki thanks, fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake has nothing to do with expectation values; $(w\cdot x)^2=\|w\|_2^2\cdot\|x\|_2^2$ is wrong already before you substitute it into the expectation. For example, consider $w\perp x$.

You need to be more careful about what the dots that you write mean. Inside the parentheses they refer to a dot product, which you write in a form that isn’t compatible with the notation for matrix multiplication. If you want to treat the dot product as a matrix multiplication (which you do if you apply the associative law in the form $(x^\top\cdot w^\top)\cdot(w\cdot x)=x^\top\cdot w^\top\cdot w\cdot x=x^\top\cdot(w^\top\cdot w)\cdot x$), you need to write it as $x^\top\cdot w$. If you do that, you’ll find that in the centre you have not $w^\top\cdot w$ but $w\cdot w^\top$, which is a matrix, not a dot product.

Comment: Thank you. I should have seen by myself that my derivation leads to an obvious contradiction.